# Crop image poor quality when retrieved

Tags: java, android, android-intent, crop

I'm trying to crop an image from the gallery, and it's working fine.

My only problem is that when I retrieve the image from the intent, its quality is really poor.

I've tried searching around the web, but can't seem to find a solution.

I think I'm getting the thumbnail version of the picture that's cropped and not the full-sized one.

This is my code:

```
 ....
 Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
 photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
 photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
 photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
 photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", "false");
 photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
 photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.toString());
 startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);
 .....

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (imageReturnedIntent != null) {
                    Bundle extras = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();
                    Bitmap profilePicture = extras.getParcelable("data");
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    profilePicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] galleryImgArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    Intent int1 = new Intent(FeedActivity.this, PostActivity.class);
                    int1.putExtra("galleryImgArray", galleryImgArray);
                    startActivity(int1);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

How do I go about getting the full-sized version of the cropped image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Android does not have a crop `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one. Also, `ACTION_PICK` is [not documented to have a `data` extra response](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK).

Comment: @CommonsWare What's your point? The crop intent works on most devices. My question was why the picture quality was low, not whether this works or not.

Comment: "The crop intent works on most devices" -- no, it does not. "My question was why the picture quality was low" -- since you are grabbing an undocumented extra value from a response, you have no basis for expecting that undocumented extra value to have any particular criteria, such as image quality. The only legitimate place that I know if where `data` is an expected extra response is with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, and there it's *supposed* to be a low-quality thumbnail. I suggest you get the *real* image, then use an image cropping library, so you are better control over the quality.